# File Locksmith opens when I try to pin an exe to the Start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I am trying to pin a .exe (for a portable app) to my Windows 10 Start menu. When I right-click the file and select "Pin to Start" File Locksmith opens, and after a few seconds displays "No results". The file is not pinned to my Start menu.
Any idea why I can't pin it?

Comment: I don't think you can pin a portable App to the Start Menu because Windows will not find it if the portable App is disconnected.

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean by "disconnected"?

Comment: Most portable Apps I know are on a USB key. If that is unplugged, it is disconnected

Comment: This is on my C: drive. I don't see why I shouldn't be able to pin it to the Start menu???

Comment: Then just use the Desktop App and you can Pin it.

Comment: If Windows won’t pin the app, then there is nothing you can do. Put a shortcut to the app on your Desktop.

Comment: I don't have the desktop app - just the portable version

Comment: As I noted, if Windows won’t pin it there is nothing you can do. The are Apps and Shortcuts that Windows will not pin. So make a shortcut to the app and place the shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: This sounds like a bug with File Locksmiths shell handler.  Have you tried *left* dragging to the start menu?  Have you tried disabling the shell extension to see if it persists?  You can also go to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and directly create a shortcut in there.

Comment: Many thanks -  pasted a shortcut to the .exe file in %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and have now managed to pin it to the Start Menu